# != Operator Not getting the Data from External System-Teradata Using OData

Tags: lightning-connect, informatica

I have the query on externla objects

```
[select customer_name__c,complete_order_status__c from current_year_order_summary__x where complete_order_status__c  != 'C' LIMIT 2000];
```

I am facing the error if i am applying the **!=** condition in query but i am able to get the data when using the **=** operator.
Please suggest me what could be the cause.
Note:We are fetching the data through OData URL in external Data Sources in salesforce.

> Error: Error received from the external system: 500:
>   com.informatica.cloud.api.adapter.runtime.exception.ReadException:
>   java.sql.SQLException: [Teradata Database] [TeraJDBC 15.10.00.14]
>   [Error 3707] [SQLState 42000] Syntax error, expected something like a
>   'SUCCEEDS' keyword or a 'MEETS' keyword or a
>   'PRECEDES' keyword or an 'IN' keyword or a
>   'CONTAINS' keyword between the word
>   'complete_order_status' and '|'.

Comment: The error message doesn't appear to match your description of the issue.

Comment: yeay ray, From error message we are not able to find the cause for it,but this only facing when we apply the != condition.And it looks like OData is not interpreting with external system.

Comment: Try <> which is an alternate way to say !=

Comment: Hello Dehler, I have tried <>, != and NOT IN also but it is not working.